# replace all $ signs by `jQuery` with bash

Tags: bash

I need to write a bash script that will first combine a few files into one and then replace all `$` signs with string `jQuery`. I'm doing well till the replacing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Run this script in this directory to compile the fixed query widget

# where we'll write the output to
OUT="compliled.js"

# path to dependencies

# combine all the dependencies into a single file in the right order (without jquery)
cat  first_component.js <(echo) \
     second_component.js <(echo) \
     third_component.js <(echo) \
    > $OUT

#replace all $ with jQuery
sed -i 's/$/jQuery/g' $OUT
```

But this way the result is `jQuery` string at the end of each line and all $'s untouched. Could someone please explain me what is going on here and maybe how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`$` is a special character denoting the end of each line in regular expressions, so you should escape it with a backslash:

```
sed -i 's/\$/jQuery/g' $OUT
          ^^
```